# Excel Formula to Identify 3rd "full" week of Month

Tags: excel, date, calendar, formula, recurring

I'm creating a workplace calendar which uses formulas to identify the dates of key department events.  One event I am trying to create on the calendar is the monthly department Town Hall, which is scheduled to occur on Wednesday of the 3rd "full" week of each month.  I say the third full week because some months start off on a Wednesday or later which results in a partial week.

Is there a complex nested (or simple) formula I could use to identify the Wednesday of third "full" week of a new month, based of a date value in the first column of a table.  Using Monday or Tuesday as the baseline to determine if the first week is a "full" week, since weekends wouldn't count for business purposes.

Sincerely,
Kristopher

[image]

Comment: On what day of the week does your full week start?

Answer (score 1):

Using A19 as the reference data as it has the 1st day of the month desired:

```
=A19+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(a19-1),1,7,6,5,4,3,2)+15
```

This assumes that the first full week starts one or before a Monday.

Comment: Thank you, Scott!  This provided me with a great solution to build off of.  I modified to the following to get consistent dates down the table 
<br/><br/>
`=DATE($A$16,MONTH([@Date]),1)+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(DATE($A$16,MONTH([@Date]),1)-1),1,7,6,5,4,3,2)+15`  
<br/><br/>
Then I added an if statement to confirm the date and add the event itself to the table. 
<br/><br/>
`=IF([@Date]=DATE($A$16,MONTH([@Date]),1)+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(DATE($A$16,MONTH([@Date]),1)-1),1,7,6,5,4,3,2)+15,"TownHall","")`

Answer (score 0):

I took ScottCramers suggestion, which worked well on the first days of the month for identifying the Wednesday of 3rd full week, then edited it a but to meet my exact needs.  His formula worked perfectly on the first day of a month, in identifying the 3rd Wednesday in comparison.  So I added the following to maintain the first day in relation to the row throughout the table

`=DATE($A$16,MONTH([@Date]),1)+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(DATE($A$16,MONTH([@Date]),1)-1),1,7,6,5,4,3,2)+15`

This maintained the first day of month for every row.  Then I added the following to compare the rows date to the formulated date, and if it was a match then that day is the TownHall event.

`=IF([@Date]=DATE($A$16,MONTH([@Date]),1)+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(DATE($A$16,MONTH([@Date]),1)-1),1,7,6,5,4,3,2)+15,"TownHall","")`

[image]